# Cannot debug on Odroid (ARM CPU) using Qt SDK

Tags: qt, debugging, arm, odroid

i installed Qt creator on Odroid XU4 but it cannot debug. I configured the path debugger as attached picture [configure debugger path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LySiS.jpg) but it still cannot work.

Could you guide me how to resolve it?

Comment: I can't even install qt-sdk on my odroid. It doesn't exist in teh repository. How did you succeed?